# How to make product free for some customers and paid for others?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to offer my new product (a spot for advertising on a list) to my first 50 customers for free and for the 51st+ customers to be paid. Is there a way using Woocommerce to create this type of setting?

Basically, I want the site to identify when 50 people have purchased and to change the product to, at that point, start charging a price.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt offer your product at normal price, but have a variation on it that reduces the price to 0, and limit the stock quantity to 50 for that variation.

If that doesn't work, create two products, one at normal price, one for free, again, limit the product in-stock quantity, and then hide any products that are sold out.